# Where-clause with left joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: products and products_actions.

When the user clicks away a product, I want this action to be stored in products_actions. The field `has_removed` will be 1 then.

I would like to present to the user only those products that he has not clicked away.

Currently I have the following entries in my tables:

Table "products":

```
id: 1
name: Product 1

id: 2
name: Product 2

id: 3 
name: Product 3
```

Table "products_actions":

```
id: 1 
id_product: 2
has_removed: 1
```

If the user has not removed a product from his page so far, there will be no corresponding entry in the products_actions table.

So my query is:

```
$qb->select('p')
            ->leftJoin(
                'ProductsActions',
                'pa',
                'WITH',
                'pa.idProduct = p.id'
            ) 
            ->where('pa.hasRemoved != 1');
```

How do I achieve that my query aboves delivers "Product 1" and "Product 3" as entries?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely clear what you need. I guess you are talking probably like this :

```
select * from products where id not in (select id_product from products_actions where hasRemoved = 1)
```

Comment: using `not in` is very dangerous to recommend without a caveat statement about nullability